# Is $d(x,y)=(x-y)^2$ a valid metric in $\mathbb R$?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

> Is $d(x,y)=(x-y)^2$ a valid metric in  $\mathbb R$?

So obviously $d(x,y)=(x-y)^2\ge0$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb R$ and equality iff $x=y$, and is also symmetric $d(x,y)=d(y,x)$. But how do I check if $d(x,z)\le d(x,y)+d(y,z)$ ?

I tried $d(x,z)=(x-z)^2=\lvert x-z\rvert ^2\le (\lvert x-y\rvert + \lvert y-z \rvert)^2$ but there is a leftover $2\lvert x-y \rvert \lvert y-z \rvert$ term

Comment: Though this doesn't actually answer your question, it's relevant that $d(x,y)=f(|x-y|)$ is a metric for any convex function $f$ - so $d(x,y)=\sqrt{|x-y|}$ is a metric. (Unfortunately, $x\mapsto x^2$ is concave, so this can and does fail)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

$$(3-1)^2\stackrel{\color{red}?}\le (3-2)^2+(2-1)^2$$

Answer (score 6):

$$d(x,z)\le d(x,y)+d(y,z) \iff (y-x)(y-z) \ge 0$$

not always true! Triangle inequality fails.

Answer (score 5):

It's not a metric:

$(1-0)^2+(2-1)^2 \leq(2-0)^2$