# How do I prove triangle inequality for this metric?

Tags: metric-spaces, normed-spaces, triangle-inequality

I am not exactly sure how to prove triangle inequality for this metric. For other metrics the proof was more intuitive, I hope you can help me out.

$$d(x,y) = |x-y|^{3}$$

Comment: Can you prove it for $:d(x,y)=|x-y|$?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.   [Here is a similar but different question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1109579/is-dx-y-x-y2-a-valid-metric-in-mathbb-r)

Answer (score 1):

Consider $x=0, z=1, $ and $y=2$.

$d(x,y)=8, d(x,z)=1, $ and $d(y,z)=1$,

so the triangle inequality is not satisfied, and your $d(x,y)$ is not a metric.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to prove this more General?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking, but a single counterexample is sufficient to disprove a claim (such as "d is a metric"); and this "d" satisfies the triangle inequality for some points (take $x=y$, for example)

Comment: Oh I am sorry I somehow read the inequality is satisfied. OK thank you a lot